# API authorization with API Login and API Key

Tags: authorization, access-token

I'm working with not best documented API and they gave me the following credentials for POST API:

```
----API Login
MFabca......j
    ----API Key
Nkey...........x
    ----API CryptKey
3YabCD............x
```

So I need to update expired Auth token used with curl call like below:

```
--header "Authorization: Basic habc............................xyz="
```

How can I get that updated token ? I tried use  APILogin:APIKEY  in base64 and without, nothing worked. API Crypt key I assume used for body encryption.
Also tried to test in PostMan, once selected **API Key** option, I need to enter `key` and `value` , should I use ? :

```
Key:  x-api-key  
Value: Nkey...........x
```

I tried this and it didn't work too. Response says:

```
Your request was made with invalid credentials
```

I assume that this API works only with Basic authentication.